# How to write rss feed generator using java jsp?

Tags: java, rss

I have a blog that have a number of blog posts. How do I generate the rss feed for these blog posts? What will the development effort be like? Would appreciate if someone can share any specific code examples, links to API.

Comment: That's way too broad of a question.

Comment: It's trivial, because all an RSS feed is is a specific format. There are libraries, too. Where specifically are you having issues?

Comment: Any recommendation on easy to use library to implement rss feed

Answer (score 1):

RSS is a simple XML. You just simply need to output data on fixed format.

[Here](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2003/08/08/rss.html) is a good example of this.

Comment: Link is down, Oracle kill it.